# Drawer Layout MenuItems Only Updating Once, then returning Null?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, sharedpreferences, navigation-drawer

I have an option within my DrawerLayout Nav Menu that swaps the text for the NavMenuItemView to the corresponding "Enable Dark Mode" or "Disable Dark Mode". This goes to a shared preference (which is what the editor variable is) and WORKS for the first time. This means that it will say either of the two responses depending on the current theme mode. Then, when I go to swap them, it will swap the actual colors, but will NOT update the "Enable Dark Mode" text, now being blank. (the XML text)

Heres the Code:

```
 private Toolbar toolbar;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private NavigationMenuItemView night;
    Menu menu;
    String imagesDir;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        night = drawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.NightMode);
        navigationView.bringToFront();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.open,R.string.close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        this.menu = menu;
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
        night = drawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.NightMode);
        if (night != null) {
            if (SplashActivity.isDarkModeOn) {
                night.setTitle("Disable Dark Mode");
            } else {
                night.setTitle("Enable Dark Mode");
            }
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return true;
    }
@Override
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id){
        case R.id.NightMode:
                night = drawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.NightMode);
                if (night != null){
                    if (SplashActivity.isDarkModeOn) {
                        night.setTitle("Disable Dark Mode");
                        SplashActivity.editor.putBoolean(
                                "isDarkModeOn", false);
                        SplashActivity.editor.apply();
                        AppCompatDelegate
                                .setDefaultNightMode(
                                        AppCompatDelegate
                                                .MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                    }
                    else {
                        night.setTitle("Enable Dark Mode");
                        SplashActivity.editor.putBoolean(
                                "isDarkModeOn", true);
                        SplashActivity.editor.apply();
                        AppCompatDelegate
                                .setDefaultNightMode(
                                        AppCompatDelegate
                                                .MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
}
```

I have tried Invalidating the options menu every time the onCreate is called, and also moving the actual update from onCreateOptionsMenu to onCreate. Neither change the behavior, of it doing the correct task once (changing the text and updating the view), but then saying "null" every time after that.

Comment: `setDefaultNightMode` is going to restart your activity to apply the new mode. Does your `SplashActivity.isDarkMode` actually read the newly updated value from SharedPreferences when you call it?

Comment: Yes, it reads the SplashActivity.isDarkMode from SharedPreferences. It works behind the scenes, it just wont update the visual element (Enable/Disable Dark mode). It DOES update the theme correctly, every time.